# Negative time Error in sencha touch

Tags: android, extjs, ant, sencha-touch-2

I am getting this error while building my sencha app using

```
sencha app build production

C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\.sencha\app\resources-impl.xml:7: java.lang.IllegalArgum
entException: Negative time
```

The app works fine in localhost ( localhost/activLearn2 ),but on building it throws this error. The error occurs in the last few lines.

```
Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84
[INF]
[INF] init-plugin:
[INF]
[INF] cmd-root-plugin.init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-properties:
[INF]
[INF] init-sencha-command:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] app-build-impl:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -init-local:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-local:
[INF]
[INF] init-local:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-path:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-environment:
[INF]
[INF] find-cmd-in-shell:
[INF]
[INF] init-cmd:
[INF]      [echo] Using Sencha Cmd from C:\Users\Rahul\bin\Sencha\Cmd\4.0.4.84 f
or C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build.xml
[INF]
[INF] -before-init:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF] Initializing Sencha Cmd ant environment
[INF] Adding antlib taskdef for com/sencha/command/compass/ant/antlib.xml
[INF]
[INF] -after-init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -after-init-defaults:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] init:
[INF]
[INF] -before-build:
[INF]
[INF] refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -before-refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\touch\src
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\app.js
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\app
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\temp\production\acti
vLearn2\sencha-compiler\app
[WRN] C1000: Rhino Parse Warning (Trailing comma is not legal in an ECMA-262 obj
ect initializer =>                  },) -- C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\app\controlle
r\Main.js:13:11
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\temp\production\acti
vLearn2\sencha-compiler\app
[INF] Concatenating output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/build/temp/production
/activLearn2/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : @full-page => @overrides
[INF] Loading classpath entry C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\temp\production\acti
vLearn2\sencha-compiler\cmd-packages.js
[INF] Adding external reference : Ext.util.Observable => C:\wamp\www\activLearn2
/build/temp/production/activLearn2/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF]
[INF] -refresh-app:
[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending concatenated output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.js

[INF] Appending content to C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/bootstrap.json
[INF]
[INF] -refresh:
[INF]
[INF] -after-refresh:
[INF]
[INF] resolve:
[INF]
[INF] js:
[INF]
[INF] -before-js:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -detect-app-build-properties:
[INF]
[INF] -compile-js:
[INF] Concatenating output to file C:\wamp\www\activLearn2/build/production/acti
vLearn2/app.js
[INF]
[INF] -js:
[INF]
[INF] -after-js:
[INF]
[INF] resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-inherit-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -before-copy-resources:
[INF]
[INF] -init:
[INF]
[INF] -init-compiler:
[INF]
[INF] -resources:
[INF] merging resources into C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\production\activLearn
2\resources
[INF] merged 0 resources into C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\production\activLear
n2\resources
[INF] merging resources into C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\build\production\activLearn
2
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 4 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:291: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
C:\wamp\www\activLearn2\.sencha\app\resources-impl.xml:7: java.lang.IllegalArgum
entException: Negative time
```

Also i checked a .sencha/app/build-impl.xml:291,which is this

```
<x-ant-call unless="skip.resources">
            <target name="-before-resources"/>
```

And the 7th line is actually a comment

```
<!--
********************************** DO NOT EDIT **********************************

This file will be replaced during upgrades so DO NOT EDIT this file. If you need to
adjust the process, reading and understanding this file is the first step.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: why you not check .sencha\app\resources-impl.xml in line 7?

Comment: there are comments on that line

Comment: show us that line pls

Comment: added in the question

Comment: did you forget `-->`?

Comment: Its an autogenerated file and there are 40 lines of comment, so i have posted only few lines. I havent edited this file. And yes the comment closes after 40 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was causing problem is that i was  including  font files ( Lato.ttf ) in the resources/icons folder. And that why it was giving negative time error. Placing them in a separate fonts folder solved the problem